# How to output '0' if $sum is empty?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I try to ouput the total turnover from all orders within the last 7 days, 30 days, 1 year, etc.

It works fine, until the $sum is empty. If $sum is empty I would like to output '0'. Means, if no document is created in the last 7 days e.g., I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined

```
  let total = await Order.aggregate([
    {$match : {"createdAt":{"$gt":new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*7 * 1000)}}},
    
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '',
        "total": {
        $sum:  '$getCartTotalPrice'
          }
      }
    }
  ]).exec();

  console.log(total)

  const totalTurnover = total[0];
  const data = totalTurnover.total.toLocaleString('de');

  res.json(data)
})
```

Comment: Why not `if total == undefined` build your response

Comment: Since total is an array, you can do `const totalTurnover = total[0]; {total} = totalTurnover || { total: 0 }; const data = total.toLocaleString('de');`
`

Comment: Thanks! But now I get this error: 

{total} = totalTurnover || {total: 0}
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

Comment: Ok, I solved it this way: 

`const totalTurnover = total[0] || 0;`

`if (totalTurnover == 0) { const data = totalTurnover; res.json(data)} 
else { const data = totalTurnover.total.toLocaleString('de');
res.json(data)}`